# Al desinstalar mi aplicacion de android no se eliminan la informacion de la base de datos (SQLite)

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Durante el desarrollo de la app, instale la aplicación en un dispositivo con android 9. Posteriormente, en la base de datos tuve que agregar una tabla nueva y por lo tanto desinstale la app para que al ejecutar se vieran los cambios. Pero sucede que al reinstalar no se agrega la nueva tabla y un campo de una tabla se esta manteniendo en la base de datos.

Esta es mi clase de configuracion de mi bd

```java
public class DBCreator extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final static int VERSION = 1;
    private final static String NAME = "kanban";
    private static DBCreator instance;

    public static void createInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBCreator(context);
        }
    }

    public static DBCreator getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private DBCreator(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DBQuery.CREATE_TABLE_DASHBOARD);
        db.execSQL(DBQuery.CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORY);
        db.execSQL(DBQuery.CREATE_TABLE_TASK);
        db.execSQL(DBQuery.CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

El error que me sale es:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: dashboard (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM dashboard ORDER BY mainDashboard DESC
```

La tabla que "no he creado" es

```java
    public final static String TABLE_DASHBOARD = "dashboard";
    public final static String ID_DASHBOARD = "idDashboard";
    public final static String MAIN_DASHBOARD = "mainDashboard";
    public final static String TITLE = "title";
    public final static String DESCRIPTION = "description";

    public final static String CREATE_TABLE_DASHBOARD = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DASHBOARD + " ("
            + ID_DASHBOARD + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + TITLE + " VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE, "
            + DESCRIPTION + " VARCHAR(255), "
            + MAIN_DASHBOARD + " TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 "
            + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tienes definida la misma versión de la Base de datos:

```
 private final static int VERSION = 1;
```

Si es que tienes problemas al ver otra estructura de la base de datos, aumenta el valor de la versión para que cree la nueva estructura:

```
 private final static int VERSION = 2;
```

y de esta forma se llame el método :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DBQuery.CREATE_TABLE_DASHBOARD);
        db.execSQL(DBQuery.CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORY);
        db.execSQL(DBQuery.CREATE_TABLE_TASK);
        db.execSQL(DBQuery.CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Ya lo intente pero no fue eso. El problema fue el mismo.
No se si podría ser un caso aislado del dispositivo, porque ya probe con otro movil y la bd se actualizo correctamente

Comment: He tenido un problema similar en alguna ocasión, resulta que la BD estaba siendo "atrapada" por otro proceso, reinicia tu dispositivo y trata nuevamente. @JohnNS

Comment: Imagine que algo asi era y ya habia intentado eso antes pero no funciono :/ ... de cualquier manera acabo de reiniciar mi dispositivo por cualquier cosa, pero el error es el mismo

Comment: Cual es el valor de TABLE_DASHBOARD?

Comment: Viene en la parte de abajo de mi pregunta el valor que le corresponde CREATE_TABLE_DASHBOARD

Los otros valores son:

    public final static String TABLE_DASHBOARD = "dashboard";
    public final static String ID_DASHBOARD = "idDashboard";
    public final static String MAIN_DASHBOARD = "mainDashboard";
    public final static String TITLE = "title";
    public final static String DESCRIPTION = "description";

Answer (score 0):

La única solución que encontré es cambiar el nombre a la base de datos, por ejemplo:

```
private final static String NAME = "kanban";
```

a

```
private final static String NAME = "kanban_db";
```

y ya funciono por completo, ya puedo agregar cambios nuevos a la base de datos. Aunque aun hay un error, ahora se crean dos bases de datos (la que tenia el anterior nombre y la del nuevo nombre).

Sin embargo, hago énfasis en que al final fue un caso aislado en el dispositivo que estoy probando la app (motorola one vision, android 9). En otros moviles la bd se crea y actualiza normal.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de desinstalar la aplicación borra el almacenamiento de la aplicación desde ajustes o configuración de tu dispositivo ,**NO BORRES PRIMERO EL CACHE** es mas, ni lo necesitas borrar, borra solo los datos almacenados esto va a borrar las bases de datos que tenga creadas y si vas a seguir programando corre de nuevo la aplicación desde donde estés programando sin desinstalarlo, no es necesario desinstalar.

Comment: ¿Sería posible que argumentes _por qué_ no debería eliminar primero la caché? (dado el énfasis que le diste)